# whereIn 10 limit Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a query that will help me to build tickets for all the current user following,
but when the list is getting bigger (above 10) it is giving me an error that 10 is the limit.
here is the code:

```
buildFollowingTickets() {
    if (!widget.followingList.isEmpty) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: userRef.where('id', whereIn: widget.followingList).get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return loading();
          }

          List<UserTicket> userFollowing = [];
          final followings = snapshot.data.docs;
          for (var following in followings) {
            final id = following.data()['id'];
            final displayName = following.data()['displayName'];
            final photoUrl = following.data()['photoUrl'];
            final UserTicket userTicket = UserTicket(
              displayName: displayName,
              photoUrl: photoUrl,
              id: id,
            );
            userFollowing.add(userTicket);
          }
          return ListView(
            children: userFollowing,
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

WhereIn can only look for a list below 10 and im trying to figure out how to change that...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cloud Firestore provides limited support for logical OR queries. The in, and array-contains-any operators support a logical OR of up to 10 equality (==) or array-contains conditions on a single field. `For other cases, create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.` (Documentation reference - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!
I decided to change it into a stream builder and now its works - I also change my database a little bit

```
buildFollowersTickets() {
    if (!widget.followersList.isEmpty) {
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: followersRef
            .doc(widget.followersId)
            .collection('userFollowers')
            .orderBy('displayName', descending: false)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return loading();
          }

          List<UserTicket> userFollowers = [];
          final followers = snapshot.data.docs;
          for (var follower in followers) {
            final id = follower.data()['id'];
            final displayName = follower.data()['displayName'];
            final photoUrl = follower.data()['photoUrl'];
            final UserTicket userTicket = UserTicket(
              displayName: displayName,
              photoUrl: photoUrl,
              id: id,
            );
            userFollowers.add(userTicket);
          }
          return ListView(
            children: userFollowers,
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```